# Handling 400 Bad Requests

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

When sending parameters as form data parameters instead of x-www-form-urlencoded parameters, my API returns an http 500 error. 
I want the API to return http 400 bad request error along with a error number and appropriate error message.
My API method has  @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED }) annotation

So I wrote an exception mapper to handle NotSupportedException.
But during the execution https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.6/jersey/jersey-server/xref/org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/routing/MethodSelectingRouter.html is called before my mapper and it throws NotSupportedException. But I want to customize the error shown to the user.

Comment: It better to place pre-process program which checks parameters and return 400 bad request before main server-side program.

Comment: I wrote a server side filter (Container Request Filter) to handle 400 bad request. I was able to throw a customized exception when there was no consumes annotation. But with consumes annotation, MethodSelectingRouter is getting called first and it throws NotSupportedException.